# Is there a way to retrieve an encoding-converted resultset from a DB?

Tags: php, database, encoding

Situation:
2 Databases, one encoded in latin1, one in UTF8.

I'm trying to write a script that reads something from the UTF8-DB and compare it to the latin1-DB, then write something to the latin1 DB.

I'd like to retrieve the results from UTF8-DB, encoded as latin1.

Is this possible without writing a custom multidimensional-array-traversing utf8_decode() function and applying it to the resultset array in PHP?

Either through mysql/postgres, PDO or just simpler PHP commands?

Answer (score 1):

Database approach

```
SELECT  CONVERT(columnlatin1 USING utf8)
FROM table;
```

PHP decoder

```
function utf8_decode_deep(&$input) {

      if (is_string($input)) {
          $input = utf8_decode($input);
      } else if (is_array($input)) {
          foreach ($input as &$value) {
              utf8_decode_deep($value);
          }

          unset($value);
      } else if (is_object($input)) {
          $vars = array_keys(get_object_vars($input));

          foreach ($vars as $var) {
              utf8_decode_deep($input->$var);
          }
      }
  }
```